# linux redhat + yum local repository VS direct download from redhat site by yum

Tags: linux, rhel, yum, repository

when I use yum to installed rpm on my redhat machine

I can do it from the local repository

or direct from redhat site ( we just disable the repository bu enable=0 as following down )

```
 [updates]
 name=Red Hat Enterprise Linux $releasever - $basearch
 baseurl=http://linux-server/mnt/src/yum/$releasever/$basearch/updates
 enabled=0
 gpgcheck=0
```

so my question is

what the advantage of yum local repository VS direct download rpm from red-hat site by yum

example when I download rpm from redhat site

```
yum install ntp
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package ntp.x86_64 0:4.2.6p5-10.el6.1 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, local repositories essentially contain a cached copy of the downloaded packages. It's good for installing quickly (as it doesn't need to be downloaded) or if, for whatever reason, you don't have a network connection.

On the other hand, it's less likely to be the most up-to-date version of the package, so it would be preferable to download from an official remote repository.